# wchar_t* to short int conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

One of the function in a 3rd party class return a`wchar_t*` that holding a resource id (I don't know why it uses wchar_t* type ) I need to convert this pointer to `short int`

This method, using AND operator works for me. but it seems like not the correct way. is there any proper way to do this?

```
wchar_t* s;
short int b = (unsigned long)(s) & 0xFFFF;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wchar_t* s; // I assume this is what you meant
short int b = static_cast<short int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(s))
```

You could also replace `short int b` with `auto b`, and it will be deduced as `short int` from the type of the right-hand expression.

Comment: I think this is the correct C++ way. anyone else has any comment?

Answer (score 2):

It returns the resource ID as a `wchar_t*` because that is the data type that Windows uses to carry resource identifiers.  Resources can be identified by either numeric ID or by name.  If numeric, the pointer itself contains the actual ID number encoded in its lower 16 bits.  Otherwise it is a normal pointer to a null-terminated string elsewhere in memory.  There is an [`IS_INTRESOURCE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648028(v=vs.85).aspx) macro to differentiate which is the actual case, eg:

```
wchar_t *s = ...;
if (IS_INTRESOURCE(s))
{
    // s is a numeric ID...
    WORD b = (WORD) s;
    ...
}
else
{
    // s is a null-terminated name string
    ...
}
```

Comment: Issue is `s` can me less that `0` so cant use unsigned short?

Comment: If the `IS_INTRESOURCE()` macro returns true then the high bits of the pointer are zero, and so the value of the pointer is not negative.  And since the size of a pointer is always greater than 16 bits, you can safely extract the low 16 bits and treat them as an unsigned short. The Win32 API uses the `WORD` type (an unsigned 16bit type) to represent numeric resource IDs, they are never negative.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean in your code `wchar_t *s;`?

I'd do the conversion more explicit using

```
short int b = reinterpret_cast<short int>(s);
```

Comment: I don't have my C++ standard on me, but I'm a bit surprised that this compiles (which it does in Visual Studio 2010). A pointer is a different size to a short, and usually reinterpret_cast requires the types to have the same size. For example, cppreferencecom [1] says that "Any pointer can be converted to any integral type large enough to hold the value of the pointer".  [1]: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: Good comment. I'll research that.

Comment: yes you are right `*` typo error, I corrected the question

Comment: VC++ compiler gives  truncate warning for this method

Comment: Yes, that can be understood. So Jim's method is "cleaner".

Answer (score 0):

If it fits your application needs, I suggest using a data type with a fixed nr of bits, e.g. uint16_t. Using short int means you only know for sure your variable has at least 16 bits. An additional question: Why do you not use unsigned short int, instead of (signed) short int?

In general, knowing the exact nr of bits make things a little more predictable, and makes it easier to know exactly what happens when you cast or use bitmasks.